# Cascading Typeaheads in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, typeahead.js

I'm new to angular, and in the pre-angular past, I have used the twitter typeahead plugin's replace() function to produce a cascading effect (i.e. change the remote url query based on the value of a different typeahead).  Now I'm using angular and the [angular-typeahead](https://github.com/Siyfion/angular-typeahead) plugin and I have no idea how to produce the same cascading functionality.
Two additional wrinkles:

1. The typeaheads appear multiple times in a ng-repeat block
2. The model values that are getting set by these typeaheads occur in a pretty nested object graph.  (e.g. $scope.filterCollection[i].filterLines[j].typeaheadProp1, etc.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you put code with you problem on plnkr.co so that we can help you? Also there are pretty self explaining [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/AT2RhpE4Qhj4iN5qMtdi?p=preview) of how use this plugin, have you seen it?

Comment: That example doesn't cover my situation b/c it doesn't involve changing the query url based on another value in scope.